# How to deal with lib/arm/<.so file> file or folder missing?

Tags: .so, android-native-library

I'm facing a challenge with my app from playstore. My app has the .so files which are in jniLibs folder for different ABIs.  My app works well during testing but when I download from play store,  logs show that lib/arm/.so file or  folder is missing.  However,  when I download the universal apk directly from my console,  it works and it has the 4 abi folders each with my .so file.
I don't know why the apk generated for delivery lacks the lib folder.  If anyone knows the solution, please tell me.  I have made several updates but nothing seems to work. I unzipped the app I downloaded from play store and found out that it didn't have the lib folder inside.